# Google Sheets - Compare Differing Rows

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a two spreadsheets with that are practically clones of each other, however there are some differences. I would like to compare two sheets. I will take care of importing it so that it can be easier to compare.

What I am comparing are rows of information including Name, Address, Status. Over the course of time, the status has been updated in one of the sheets. I'd like to be able to identify cells within the rows that are not alike.

Comment: it's difficult, except you will find the first row that has difference, because after the first difference row, all rest will differ

Comment: Welcome. Would you please summarise the research that you have done.

Comment: Hi, I can describe it a bit more. I have several staff and they each edit a document with names of people and the status of each client. They make changes every week. I have it set up where they fill in a clone and I transfer their answers into another document. So, when they update it weekly I'd like to be able to easily see what was changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Google Apps Script. The following code works as an example to accomplish this:

```js
var OTHER_SPREADSHEET_ID = "OTHER_SPREADSHEET_ID";
var NUM_COLUMNS = 4;

function checkDifferences() {
  var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(OTHER_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var thisValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, NUM_COLUMNS).getValues();
  var otherValues = otherSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, NUM_COLUMNS).getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<lastRow; i++) {
    if (!rowsAreEqual(thisValues[i], otherValues[i])) {
      // Mark row
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, NUM_COLUMNS).setBackground("yellow");
    }
  }
}

function rowsAreEqual(row1, row2) {
  for (var i=0; i<row1.length; i++) {
    if (row1[i] !== row2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Simply explained, the code does the following:

1. Open the Spreadsheet that you want the current spreadsheet to be compared to.
2. For each row, if the rows differ change the background color of the "host" Spreadsheet (the Spreadsheet that has the code bound to).

#### Example

[image]

[image]

After executing the code (bound to the "Modified" Spreadsheet) the sheet becomes as follows:

[image]

#### References

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html)

Comment: Is there anything I can do when it says app isn't verified after the try to run it?

Comment: This is the error that appears: "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."